# When using a Recon Drone for Tau Pathfinders in Kill Team (narrative campaign), how many other models can I use?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I'm currently playing in a narrative campaign as Tau Pathfinders, and I'm using the following operatives. Since I'm using the Recon drone, would this list be considered the correct number of models? Mostly curious if I can add an additional drone.

11 Units

- Shas'ui Pathfinder
- Assault Grenadier Pathfinder
- Blooded Pathfinder
- Communications Specialist Pathfinder
- Drone Controller Pathfinder
- Medical Technician Pathfinder
- Weapons Expert Pathfinder
- Weapons Expert Pathfinder
- Marksman Pathfinder
- Transpectral Interference Pathfinder
- MB3 Recon Drone

Comment: I believe you don't "select" the Shas'ui Pathfinder, you always have them as the LEADER

Answer (score 2):

> Since I'm using the Recon drone, would this list be considered the correct number of models?

In a standard Pathfinder kill team you have:

- 1 Shas'Ui Pathfinder
- 11 Operatives from a list which includes the MB3 Recon Drone (which counts as 2 Operatives)

So yes.

In the original version of the rules you got 12 Operatives from the list, but the Balance Dataslate reduces that by 1.

> Mostly curious if I can add an additional drone.

You can replace one of your operatives with a drone, but each done can only be picked once, so it would need to be a different type of drone.

---

Since you said you were in a narrative campaign, I should point out that the dataslate can change over the source of the campaign. Initially, however, it needs to match a normal kill team roster as yours does now.